# Converting documents to text with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: character-encoding, conversion, libreoffice

[unoconv](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv) uses LibreOffice to convert any file that LibreOffice can convert.

Now I need export to text with the **UTF-8** character encoding.

I use the following command:

```
unoconv -f txt -e FilterOptions=76 Foo.docx
```

This creates the `Foo.txt` file, but its encoding is **us-ascii** and the characters don't show correctly.

If I'm right, the `-e` option sets the export filtering options as the [man page mentions](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unoconv). What's wrong with my options?

Example of input and output files:

- Infput: [foo.odt](http://metemaddar.ir/sites/all/files/foo.odt)
- Output: [foo.txt](http://metemaddar.ir/sites/all/files/foo.txt)

Comment: What's an example of a character that isn't converted correctly? What is it converted to? Ideally, post a link to an example of a small document (with just one word or so) that doesn't convert correctly.

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks for your attention. I added the example files.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
unoconv -f txt -e FilterOptions=UTF8,LF Foo.docx
```

It seems a bug and was reported [here](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/issues/98).

If it doesn't work, maybe your LibreOffice doesn't support `docx` file. See more details [here](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/issues/1).

Comment: Many thanks @Gnouc, But this does not change the Foo.txt character encoding. still it's **us-ascii**.

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar: Maybe your LibreOffice does not support docx file. See my updated answer.

Comment: I use LibreOffice 4.3 and it supports **.docx**; I could convert **.docx** to **.odt** and also **.odt** file has the same issue.

Comment: This works for me. unoconv 0.5-1 on Debian Gnu+Linux

Comment: Thanks @richard, Compilation got error on Slackware current. But I could convert **.docx** to **.txt** using [pyton-docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx). We can also convert **.odt** to **.docx** and then covert it to **.txt** with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: BTW Just a heads up, the option **-e FilterOptions=UTF8,LF** is the default option for Text output. So there is no need to provide that one.